# Reallocated sector count & Secure Erase

Tags: hard-drive, bad-blocks

I have a retired HDD with a high "Reallocated Sector Count" (maybe greater a thousand, if I remember correctly).  Today, I performed a [ATA Secure Erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) via `hdparm`, and after that, this count becomes zero. It remains to be zero after finishing `smartctl -t long`. The "Raw Read Error Rate", "Seek Error Rate", "Reallocated Event Count", "Current Pending Sector", "Offline Uncorrectable" are also zero. I have some questions for which I don't find definitive answers after searching.

1. Why do "Reallocated Sector Count" and relevant counts become zero after Secure Erase? Does this mean that there are no real badblock and it is due to incorrect reading of SMART?
2. If these counts underestimate the real number of badblocks, how can I read the correct number of badblocks after a Secure Erase?

Comment: Maybe test it using software. Do keep in mind that SMART is a mess and every drive maker basically does what it wants.

Comment: So some bad sectors are "soft" (eg can be corrected with a full format) and others are "Hard".  I recommend formatting the disk for a filesystem and perform a full filesystem scan that checks your freespace. that should cause the "hard" bad sectors to be located and remapped again.

Comment: If you're on Windows, format the disk with a slow (not quick) format. This will write every sector and find bad sectors. For a large disk, this will take time.

Comment: @FrankThomas Do you suggest that neither ATA Secure Erase (which, if I understand correctly, fill-zero the whole device by the firmware, something at lower level than `dd if=/dev/zero`), nor `smartctl -t long` would detect and remap bad sectors?

Comment: @FrankThomas If I understand correctly, `fsck` invokes `badblocks`, which is simply performing read/write tests sector by sector, and mark all sectors with I/O errors. However, I heard that "modern" HDD's hide bad sectors in that, during an access to a bad sector, from the outside it looks like reading or writing the same sector but internally remapped to another, so the outsider no longer "knows" that this is a bad sector. I am trying to understand whether these SMART counts record the number of these internally remapped sectors, say.

Comment: so, first off, that the secure erase zeroed out your reallocated sector count, uncorrectable count, etc, there are no longer any remapped sectors. this may allow you to recover the sectors that were "soft" bad. I'm not sure about the extended smart test, but generally speaking when the OS encounters a sector that fails a write, it lists it as a current pending sector. that sector has not yet been reallocated. once chkdsk or fsck have been run over the whole disk, those current pending sectors will be remapped and either become reallocated sectors or uncorrectable sector.